# Node and JSDOM: can't seem to scrape a URL response

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, jsdom

I am trying to scrape using JSDOM and I am having an issue when grabbing a site. I am using Axios and I tested console logging the `resp` , which comes back correctly but when I use JSDOM on it, I can't seem to get any values from it.  I am testing it using `document.querySelector(".cd__headline").textContent` which I know should return a string value but I keep getting `cannot call textContent on null`.

```
 scrape: async function() {
        try {
           const resp = await axios.get("http://www.cnn.com")
           const {document} = new JSDOM(resp.data).window;
           console.log(document.querySelector(".cd__headline").textContent);
        } catch (error) {
            throw error;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you go to http://www.cnn.com and do a View Page Source and then search in that for `cd__headline`, you will find tons of CSS references to that, but no content with that.  That means the content is not in the raw source of the page and that's all the the Axios call gets you.  That content is probably being inserted dynamically with Javascript.  Since the content is not present in the HTML you get from Axios, then `document.querySelector(".cd__headline")` returns `null` and thus the error you have.

If you want to be able to view the DOM of the fully rendered page, then you need to use something like [puppeteer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer) that uses an actual browser engine (the Chromium browser engine) to "run" the page, including all of its scripts and then you get access to the fully rendered page.

When scraping content, you need to first go look at View Page Source on the actual site or do an Axios call to get the RAW HTML of the site and see if the content you want is actually in the RAW HTML or not.

Comment: @MauirceA - Does this answer your question?